# Handling "Not a valid bookmark." error with corrupted records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database that has some corrupted records.  When looking at the table within Access the records display with "#Error" in the fields.  At the same time a dialog box pops-up with "Not a valid bookmark.". While processing these records in some VBA code I get the same error (error number is 3159).  My question is this:  How can I detect these corrupted records within VBA? Can I do this without trapping that particular error?  Is there a way using SQL that I can delete these records?  I tried "compact and repair" and it didn't touch them.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to delete the offending records using VBA without success.  The records remained after the code deleted them.  I was able to work around this by manually deleting one record and then using "compact and repair".  This is what I'll have to do for the customer, I guess.  Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of corrupted database, IMO, the best solution is to create an new empty database, and import all the objects from the corrupted one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub CheckForErr(tname)
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

If Left(tname, 4) <> "Msys" Then

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(tname)

With rs
   Do While Not .EOF
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            If IsError(rs(fld.Name)) Then
               Debug.Print "Error"
            End If
        Next
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No good, the `isError` does not detect the error.  I tried `isNull` too and that didn't work.  Thanks @Remou.

Answer (score 0):

I Just had the same exact problem.

Solution :

1 - Select "Compact And Repair" : This will change the problematic "#Error" row by empty row.

2 - Delete the empty row. (They are at the end of the table normally because they are empty.)